# Kafka enabled Azure Event Hub: Invalid session timeout in Receiver

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to use the exact code provided here to send/receive data from a `Kafka` enabled `Azure Event Hub`.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/tree/master/quickstart/dotnet/EventHubsForKafkaSample

I'm successful in sending messages to the event hub, but each time I try to initialize the receiver, I get this invalid session timeout error.

```
7|2018-11-14 19:10:52.967|ssarkar#consumer-1|SEND| [thrd:sasl_ssl://ssarkar-test.servicebus.windows.net:9093/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://ssarkar-test.servicebus.windows.net:9093/0: Sent JoinGroupRequest (v0, 109 bytes @ 0, CorrId 6)
7|2018-11-14 19:10:52.992|ssarkar#consumer-1|RECV| [thrd:sasl_ssl://ssarkar-test.servicebus.windows.net:9093/bootstrap]: sasl_ssl://ssarkar-test.servicebus.windows.net:9093/0: Received JoinGroupResponse (v0, 16 bytes, CorrId 6, rtt 24.28ms)
7|2018-11-14 19:10:52.992|ssarkar#consumer-1|REQERR| [thrd:main]: sasl_ssl://ssarkar-test.servicebus.windows.net:9093/0: JoinGroupRequest failed: Broker: Invalid session timeout: actions Permanent
```

The only timeout I am specifying is the `request.timeout.ms`, and I have tried without that as well, but the error won't go away. I have also tried using various values of `session.timeout.ms` and still the error persists.

There is some info online about making sure that the session timeout value falls within the min and max of the group timeout value. But I don't have a way to view the broker configs on `Azure Event Hub`, so I have no idea what they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

EH allows session timeouts between 6000 ms and 300000 ms.  We also reject your join group request if the request's rebalance timeout is less than session timeout.

Quick note - we aren't actually running real Kafka brokers, so there is a bit of added complexity to exposing broker configs.  However, we will update our Github repository with configuration values/ranges!

11/22/19 edit - configuration doc can be found here https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md